# Google Assistant (Google Home): dynamic response based on web query

Tags: google-home

I use an Google Assistant (Google Home) and would have an answer, which my Website gives.

For Example:
- I say: Hey Google, buy 3 Eggs
- my Website is beeing called (Webhook/wget/etc.):

```
http://url.de/befehl.php?befehl=buy 3 Eggs

or without keyword

http://url.de/befehl.php?befehl=3 Eggs
```

- my Website gives following text/content: ok that was successful
- Google simply says this text, which he got from Website: ok that was successful

IFTTT can only send a command to Website (Webhook) and lets google speak a fixed answer, but not dynamic answer.

Is it possible to realize that (IFTTT, Olisto, etc.) ?

It would be possible to run a Script, which itself gets the content/text of an Website and says what the Website gives (IFTTT-Webhook could do this, but says always the same text (not dynamic)).

Any Ideas, Tipps, Tricks?

Greetings,
Niko

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible. You don't really need IFTTT.

I'll give you an example with something I am working on. I would assume you are working on Dialogflow to build your voice app.

***Important***: Calls outside the google network only work from an enterprise app **NOT** from the free version

You can just make a call from dialogflow like this for example:

```
const response = axios.post(...);
conv.ask(response.speech);
```

That is assuming your response from the server looks something like this:

```
{
  status: 200,
  speech: "ok that was successful",
  response: "ok that was successful"
}
```